# Setting controller attributes inside ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS and I'm with a doubt about the controller attributes. I created an attribute called anuncio, this attribute has an array of objects as showed in the image bellow:

```
var anuncioModule = angular.module('anuncioModule',[]);

anuncioModule.controller('RegistrationController',['$http',function ($http){


    this.anuncios;


    this.loadAnuncios = function loadAnuncios(){

         $http.get('http://localhost:8080/pederofer/anuncios/get.action').then(function(result){

             this.anuncios.push.apply(this.anuncios, result.data);
        });

    }


}]);
```

When I call my webservice with the function loadAnuncios and try to set the values directly using "this.anuncios" i get the message "this.anuncios is undefined". but if i create a var called anuncs and set "this.anuncios = anucs", and instead of set my AJAX call directly into this.anuncios I set to anucs as the image bellow,  It works.

```
var anuncioModule = angular.module('anuncioModule',[]);

var anuncs =[]; 

anuncioModule.controller('RegistrationController',['$http',function ($http){


    this.anuncios = anuncs ;


    this.loadAnuncios = function loadAnuncios(){

         $http.get('http://localhost:8080/pederofer/anuncios/get.action').then(function(result){

             anuncs.push.apply(anuncs, result.data);
        });

    }


}
```

My question is, why it works?

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest going about what you're doing in a different way.

```
var anuncioModule = angular.module('anuncioModule',[]);

anuncioModule.controller('RegistrationController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.anuncios = [];
    $scope.loadAnuncios = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/pederofer/anuncios/get.action').then(function(result) {
             $scope.anuncios = result.data;
        });
    };
}
```

I don't know if that's exactly what you're after but maybe that will make a lightbulb go off for you.